# How to make a button to behave like a table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, interface-builder

How do I customize a UIButton to behave like a table view cell?
I've tried make it in Interface Builder, but since the button is invisible and have no image, it's never gets highlighted when you press it. I want this grayed out behavior like on a table view cell.
Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand. If your button is invisible, of course you won't see it and thus it cannot have any highlight.

Comment: Why button? You can achieve this is on UIView too, just you need a TapGesture on View, on tap change the Background color, and after some time using performselector change to normal.

Comment: Okay, of course you can make your own button, but I thought maybe there was an easy way to use the UIButton and do the same... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way ever:

Make a 10x10px gray square png image, save it and name it like "greayButtBkg.png" and drag it into SupportingFiles in XCode.
Declare an Outlet of your button into your .h file and an IBAction method into your .m file.

**yourFile.h:**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

**yourFile.m:**

```
- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender {
    [_myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greyButtBkg"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Your Button will get a grey background color when you'll tap it, and go back to its Default clearColor when you'll release your finger.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly. And I found out, thanks to you, how to fix it in Interface Builder as well. In "Attributes inspector", change "State Config" to "Highlighted" and under "Background" type in the name of the grey image you created. Then you don't need to declare an Outlet.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a `Custom Control` that would behave like `UITableViewCell`. See code below

**MyButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyButton : UIView
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame selector:(SEL)sel target:(id)target;
@end
```

**MyButton.m**

```
#import "MyButton.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@interface MyButton()
@property(assign)SEL selector;
@property(assign)id target;
@end

@implementation MyButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame selector:(SEL)sel target:(id)target
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        self.selector=sel;
        self.target=target;

        self.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
        self.layer.cornerRadius=5.0;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)tapAction:(id)sender{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    }];

    [self performSelector:@selector(deSelect) withObject:nil afterDelay:.2];
}

-(void)deSelect{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [_target performSelector:_selector withObject:self];
    }];

}

/*- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
}*/

@end
```

Since, It uses `UIView` you can easily add, or draw anything on this control, and easily customize this.

Hope this helps.
Cheers.